# Timeout value with pyserial is not working on Windows

Tags: python, windows, timeout, pyserial

I'm running Python 2.7.3 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, and it's connected (via USB->RS232 cable) to a 64-bit Ubuntu machine running the same Python version (2.7.3).

I'm running into a problem where the timeout=None doesn't seem to be working correctly on the Windows 7 side and I can't figure out why.

Here's what I have on the Win side:

```
>>> import serial
>>> s = serial.Serial(3)
>>> s.baudrate = 9600
>>> s
Serial<id=0x203a320, open=True>(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N',
stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
>>> s.read(5)
''                  <--- returns right away
>>> s.timeout = 0
>>> s.read(5)
''                  <--- correctly returns right away
>>> s.timeout = 10
>>> s.read(5)       <--- correctly waits 10s
```

Now I've read the documentation [here](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read) and I know that if I give it no timeout `None` it should wait forever, and a `0` timeout it should return right away, but `None` is the default and it's not waiting... I was wondering if something had changed, but when I try the code on the Linux side, it works:

```
>>> import serial
>>> s = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")
>>> s.baudrate = 9600
>>> s
Serial<id=0x7f325e002b50, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, 
parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
>>> s.read(5)
''                  <--- correctly waits forever
>>> s.timeout = 0
>>> s.read(5)
''                  <--- correctly returns right away
>>> s.timeout = 10
>>> s.read(5)       <--- correctly waits 10s
```

Are there any known caveats when setting this up on Windows? Does anyone have ideas why I'm seeing this problem? Any ideas on other things I can try to help diagnose this failure?

Answer (score 0):

On windows 7 x64 with python 2.7.3 and pyserial 2.6 it works fine:

```
>>> import serial
>>> s = serial.Serial(1)
>>> Serial<id=0x3ea5518, open=True>(port='COM2', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
>>> s.read(5)
# ... after receiving real data ... 
'\xb99\xad\x87\xc2'
```

What version of PySerial do you use?
I've got compiled binary from Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages by Christoph Gohlke[1](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).
Maybe you should try this.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue on a Raspberry Pi. Notable is the USB-RS232 cable! This seems to have a different behaviour than a pure RS232 interface. It will always return n "0" Bytes when you read n Bytes from the Port eventhough no data is available. Especially it will fill a read request that asks for more than in_waiting promises with the aforementioned "0" Bytes. The only way around that is to use in_waiting and to only read the amount of Bytes that property promises.